# How to write a program that can interact with other programs

Tags: java

I want to write a program that could play solitaire on windows. The user would run the program and open solitaire and watch as the cards move. Its easy to write the AI for the program that would play solitaire (I obviously don't have the source code for the Windows solitaire). One way I can think of doing this is if I took an image of the solitaire and analyzed it to determine the current state of the cards, then I could pass the current state of the cards to my program, which could determine the next move. But how would I execute the clicking command.

More generally, I want to write a program that can interact with another program like a user would. 
I have experience with C, C++, Java, Ruby. But I don't know how to even get started on this, or whether this can be even done?

Comment: Doing this on Java would be tedious.

Comment: *"Its easy to write the AI for the program that would play solitaire"*  Is it?  Please share the snippet with us.  *"I have discovered a truly remarkable proof, which this comment is too small to contain."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is not the language to do this. In order to facilitate functionality like this you need to rely heavily on windows API, especially those that allow you to inject input. As a starting point I can suggest you get acquainted with how windows application actually process the input. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a good article on the subject.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure about all the other posts here, but Java has a Robot class that allows you to (easily) dispatch keyboard and mouse events to the underlying OS (windows in this case) that would allow you to do exactly what you're talking about.  It's a little class I've used loads of times to "automate" tasks on windows.

(I know this is an old thread, but in case anyone else out there in the world stumbles upon it like I have and want to do what you've outlined.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to automate Windows tasks, then use a language specifically written to perform this. Ones that come to mind include WinBatch, AutoIt, and AutoHotkey.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a method [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx) which can be used to programmatially control mouse and keyboard. If you know which application you want to control this may be enough. However, you probably also want to examine what is on the screen. For this you need [GetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a so-called "UI Automation" API which is really helpful in implementing what you ask for - some links with details/source/samples:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFUIAutomation.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winuiautomation/

**REMARK:**

Doing this from Java might be a bit hard since AFAIK you would need to use JNI for that.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't like screen scraper technologies very much, as they are often impacted by changes to the underlying application or even by changes in screen resolution.
However this seems to be an approach that you could adopt here.
I agree that java is not the best choice here.
Search for "screen scraper API" and you should find something to start you off.

Update:

The first hit that seems promising is http://community.screen-scraper.com/API
which counter-intuitively seems to be java based.

Comment: The link you provided is for scraping wb-sites - from the FAQ **screen-scraper is designed only to scrape data from web sites.** !

Comment: Oh, well as I thought java probably isn't the best choice of technology for this requirement. But I'm sure there are other screen scraping API's available for externally automating windows applications. I've seen something similar built into a software testing suite.