# Java package to select text in another program

Tags: java, windows

I found some stuff about this for C#, but I do not see anything for java:

I need to be able to select and copy text in another program on Windows using java. This will be on the same system with user logged in, not over the web. My two questions are:

Is this considered ok thing to do in programming, as I can see potential for abuse, where people can copy passwords this way?

And, is there a package that already exists in Java to do this?

In other words: I need java software equivalent of "click into active text window" "Ctrl-A" "Ctrl-C", and then I need to work with that text.

Thanks, complete newbie here,

Comment: What is the other program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a program that can interact with other programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945444/how-to-write-a-program-that-can-interact-with-other-programs)

Comment: see that's the thing: I am working with a bunch of obscure text editors that are built-in into all kinds of other software. I need to automate some things that have to do with simple text editing. So, example would be a text window in IE, like the one I am typing this into, or text part of MS word, notepad, etc.